# make: *** [install] Error 1

Tags: linux, gcc, installation

I have a problem with installing old software developed in 1995 for Linux.
My operating system is Cent Os. and I got some errors as below when I tried to follow the program instruction. I still do not know what the problems are....
sometimes the clock skew error messages show up but frequently it does not come up.

Waiting for expert's help

igrf]$ make 
make: Warning: File `igrf' has modification time 98 s in the future
make:`igrf' is up to date.
make: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.

igrf]$ make install
make: Warning: File `igrf' has modification time 94 s in the future
install -c /home/hj/master/mag/bin -m 755 ./igrf 
install: omitting directory`/home/hj/master/mag/bin'
make: *** [install] Error 1

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I installed the old version of libpcap-1.0.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 from the source, but this was not successful, as it does not fit my version of Ubuntu and gives a make `error: *** [install] Error 1`.
Instead this tar.gz archive i used the usual command in the terminal:

`sudo apt install libpcap-dev` # the problem is solved

*It is possible that there is incompatibility of archives to new versions of Ubuntu.*

It is also possible to find missing dependencies, check this:

**IMPORTANT:** There is enough information about this error; please do not post anything unless there is a specific review!

```
make install --touch
```

What can i do to help find dependencies. All of these workarounds are specific to one configuration or another. Therefore, it makes sense to track other issues as a separate bug instead of continuing to use one bug report for each issue. To make sure we focus on bugs that affect testers, `Q_A_` asks reporters to feel free to post fixes and commits. The answer was very focused on the lack of specific dependencies. It will automatically collect and attach updated debug information to your report. Please add them for the feisty to help muffle the compilation issue. Maybe even backport fixes for the dapper and edgy ones?

Initially when compiling mongoose i used the helper:

```
make --touch
```

и был вывод:

```
touch vc98
touch vc2017
touch mingw
touch mingw++
touch linux
touch fuzzer
touch fuzz
```

Then i installed the missing dependencies:

```
sudo apt install fuzz libfuzzer-10-dev ocaml-mingw-w64-x86-64 vc-dev
```

...and still not all, then i had to use install (using reportdependencies the current behavior is unexpected and unsatisfactory):
I have output for mongoose:

```
touch linux-libs
touch install
```

Reportdependencies doesn't handle this very well.
In this case, linux-libs (install is omitted) points to some missing libraries. And this:

```
sudo apt install liblinux-pid-perl
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an equivalent problem in the past. It is tied to the timestamps of (some) files. You should try to use the command "[touch](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?touch)" on the concerned files. This will update the time stamps of those files.

I hope this will make the trick.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried your solution right after I saw your answer. But still it has same problem. igrf]$ make install->              
install -c /home/hj/master/mag/bin -m 755 ./igrf->                    
install: omitting directory `/home/hj/master/mag/bin'
make: *** [install] Error 1