# How to install v8js macOS 10.13.6 - Permission denied make: *** [install-modules] Error 1

Tags: php, macos, v8js

I'm trying to installa v8js in my macOS HighSierra 10.13.6
I'm following this guide on github but when I try to install the extension using `make install` I get this error in console

```
$ make install
Installing shared extensions:     /usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/
cp: /usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/#INST@59304#: Permission denied
make: *** [install-modules] Error 1
```

I have the v8js.so module installed inside the `/Users/<username>/v8js/modules/` I think it needs to be moved into another directory to make it work? How I can fix this problem to make v8js working in my local envoirment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [make: \*\*\* \[install\] Error 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26141028/make-install-error-1)

Comment: Try `$ sudo make install`

Comment: @PaulBaiju solved using sudo, tank you for the help :)